# Detecting WinXP SP3 using MFC/C++ code returns true even in WinXP SP2

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, operating-system

Under windows 7 64bit I run my C++ app using compatibility mode "Windows XP service pack 2" and the following code which detects WinXP SP3 returns "TRUE" while it shouldn't. What seems to be wrong here ?

```
BOOL CUtils::Is_WinXP_SP3_or_Later() {

   OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;
   DWORDLONG dwlConditionMask = 0;
   int op=VER_GREATER_EQUAL;

   // Initialize the OSVERSIONINFOEX structure.

   ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
   osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
   osvi.dwMajorVersion = 5;
   osvi.dwMinorVersion = 1;
   osvi.wServicePackMajor = 3;
   osvi.wServicePackMinor = 0;
   osvi.dwBuildNumber = 2600;

   // Initialize the condition mask.

   VER_SET_CONDITION( dwlConditionMask, VER_MAJORVERSION, op );
   VER_SET_CONDITION( dwlConditionMask, VER_MINORVERSION, op );
   VER_SET_CONDITION( dwlConditionMask, VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, op );
   VER_SET_CONDITION( dwlConditionMask, VER_SERVICEPACKMINOR, op );
   //VER_SET_CONDITION( dwlConditionMask, VER_BUILDNUMBER, op );

   // Perform the test.

   return VerifyVersionInfo(
      &osvi, 
      VER_MAJORVERSION | VER_MINORVERSION | 
      VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR | VER_SERVICEPACKMINOR,
      dwlConditionMask);
}
```

Comment: I think that still reports the real version, even if you run the program in compatibility mode. But I am not sure. Only in Windows 8.1 or Win10, the system sometimes lies to you and reports a lower version if manifest is not set etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but logging the application, indeed  I get windows xp service pack 3 version. I used the GetVersionEx() which reports [Windows 5.1 Service Pack 3.0 build 2600]. So, I think something else is going on here.

Comment: `GetVersionEx` reports the version set in compatibility mode (but I don't know how you would get pack service number from that). I was saying `VerifyVersionInfo` will report the real OS version (I think)

Comment: GetVersionEx returns also the service pack. The string in the log file I showed above is a formatted version of the GetVersionEx result. I don't know about VerifyVersionInfo I have to debug it but I doubt if it returns a wrong os in compatibility mode.

Comment: `GetVersionEx()` can return the service pack major/minor version if you pass it an `OSVERSIONINFOEX` instead of an `OSVERSIONINFO`. On my Win7 64bit system, when I set compatibility mode to XP SP2, `GetVersionEx()` reports XP SP2 as expected, not SP3. But `VerifyVersionInfo()` still returns true for >= XP SP3 no matter what OS version I set the compatibility mode to (all the way down to NT4), so clearly `VersionInfoEx()` is not respecting the compatibility mode at all.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I suspected that VerifyVersionInfo() does not respect the compatibility mode but I had no time to make some tests. Anyway I changed my code to get those infos specifically from GetVersionEx() ( I also used OSVERSIONINFOEX from the beggining). Anyway, In my case - deptite of that you are saying - that runs also Win7 64bit, in compatibility mode reports XP SP3 as expected. I am curious about your results...

Comment: I told you my results. When I set the compatibility mode to XP SP2, `GetVersionEx()` reports XP SP2 as expected, it does not report XP SP3 like you claim.